# How to logout User in Spring Security with external call

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I have a Spring boot application with spring security implemented. User logging and logout successfully working and I am using jdbc to session store.
Now I just want to implement a new rest end point which is accepting userName of a particular user as a parameter and logout that user.
Currently I am using follwing class as the logout implentation.

```
@Component
public class CustomLogoutHandler extends SecurityContextLogoutHandler {

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        super.logout(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

But **my question is how to use this class or inbuilt Spring logout to logout a user from external request?**
For session_store I am using following configuration and user sessions are successfully saved in the database.

```
    #Spring Session
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.table-name= SESSION_TABLE
```

Manually deleting the table entry from the table can be done.And it will logout the user.
But I want do the logout by following the proper flow of Spring security.

Thanks

Comment: The session is bound to the user. So only the user can logout. Otherwise you would need to hijack the session. So deleting the table entry is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Can't we use sessionRegistry for retrieve user sessions and do invalidate the sessions. ?

Comment: Have you tried it? You could loop over all principals and call expireNow on the SessionInformation and then remove the SessionInformation from the registriy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use spring session to logout a specific user just autowiring the session repository in your controller.
If i well understood you have configured a JdbcOperationsSessionRepository, so you can do that :

```
@Autowired
private org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository;
```

and then use your repository to find the session related to a specific user

```
sessionRepository.findByIndexNameAndIndexValue(FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME, somePrincipalName);
```

Comment: This is giving  JdbcSession object. But spring logout method needed HttpSession object.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you need.you said  "or inbuilt Spring logout to logout a user from external request". an external request is a request not related to the user session ? If yes you can use findByIndexNameAndIndexValue method to retrieve the user session and then delete it with delete method of JdbcOperationsSessionRepository. It's the same you do by deleting from the table, but done by spring

Comment: Yes you are correct. I will do the thing this way and marked this as the answer :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would approach it:

- create a session scoped controller for logout
- create an endpoint and inject the `HttpSession` into it
- invalidate session once the endpoint is called

Something like:

```
@Scope("session")
@Controller
public class LogoutController {

@PostMapping("/logout")
public ResponseEntity logout(HttpSession session) {
session.invalidate();
return new ResponseEntity().ok();
}

}
```

Also I am not sure why you would not use the already provided logout config by Spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // config your credentials provider here
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        authorizeRequests()
         // protected endpoints config here
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

And you can directly call `/logout` using POST which will trigger the logout.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But I am already using the logout provided by Spring for logout user by him self. In my case the requirement is to logout user from external call. Not by him self.